# Dict Comprehension: appending to a key value if key is present, create a new key:value pair if key is not present

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

My code is as follows:

```
for user,score in data:
    if user in res.keys():
        res[user] += [score]
    else:
        res[user] = [score]
```

where data is a list of lists arranged as such:

```
data = [["a",100],["b",200],["a",50]]
```

and the result i want is:

```
res = {"a":[100,50],"b":[200]}
```

Would it be possible to do this with a single dictionary comprehension?

Comment: Look at the `collections` package - [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: as a sidenote, do not use `my_list + [item]` to append `item` to a list. use the dedicated `append` list method, like `my_list.append(item)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be simplified using `dict.setdefault` or `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
data = [["a",100],["b",200],["a",50]]
res = {}   #or collections.defaultdict(list)
for k, v in data:
    res.setdefault(k, []).append(v)  #if defaultdict use res[k].append(v)

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': [100, 50], 'b': [200]}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use .update for your dictionary..

```
data = [["a",100],["b",200],["a",50]]
dictionary = dict()

for user,score in data:
    if user in dictionary.keys():
        dictionary[user] += [score]
    else:
        dictionary.update({user:[score]})
```

output:

```
{'a': [100, 50], 'b': [200]}
```

Comment: No, you should **not** use `.update` here. The OPs approach is the simplest and most idiomatic way, `.update` is good for when you have another dictionary already, not for updating a single value